# Select all rows except three in using MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-order-by, where-clause

I was trying to use a `select` statement to get all the rows from a certain MySQL table except for three which has in user_id of 5,6,7. Below is the code but its not working properly. Please can you help.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 0, 20 WHERE user_id<>5,6,7";`

Comment: `WHERE` clause must go before the `ORDER BY` clause (after the `FROM` clause) [MySQL Docs for SELECT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: @MarkBaker : Can you give an example please.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_id<>5 ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 0, 20";

Comment: @MarkBaker : If i dont want more than one row let say i dont want three row 5,7,8 for this what will be the query

Comment: Right, changing the question when the answers start coming in. Always nice.

Comment: @KaranTiwari $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_id NOT IN (5,6,7) ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 0, 20"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to Use **NOT IN** function for multiple id's.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_id NOT IN (5,6,7) ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 0, 20"
```

Answer (score 2):

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_id<>5 ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 0, 20 "`

Look at [Order by](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php), [Where Clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) and [Order of operations](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm)

As you've just changed your question the new answer is

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_id NOT IN (5,6,7) ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 0, 20 "`

Look at [NOT IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM login WHERE NOT user_id = 5, ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `user_id` NOT IN (5,6,7) ORDER BY `user_id` ASC LIMIT 0, 20";
```

Comment: What a new in your answer Mr. Ajay?

Comment: the backticks @Sadikhasan

Comment: Good, For your information without `backticks` query also work fine.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I think I need to see your answer before posted mine.

Comment: Should I delete this?